Learning music theory on guitar and piano at the same time
I am interested in playing and learning both classical guitar and piano keyboard, and I can play music on both using tab/video tutorials. However, I have decided to learn music theory subjects such as, reading standard notation, understanding and playing scales, chords, etc. I have a book called "The Music Theory for Dummies" and it teaches each subject for both instruments (the placement of notes on the instrument, chords, scales,…).
As I'm interested in gaining a better understanding of both instruments, I'm wondering if it's advisable to apply each new subject I learn to both piano and guitar, and if this will help to deepen my understanding.

Yes, I think it is.

Learning about a subject in different ways is always smart. That's why many comprehensive music courses require learning a complementary instrument of a different family. It can be challenging sometimes: some subjects are "easier" to learn in a way than in another (eg.: learning harmony on polyphonic instruments such as keyboards, as opposed to doing it with monophonic ones, such as winds), but trying to achieve that "same learning" in different "fields" is rarely discouraged. Learning more is hardly a bad choice: many successful musicians are so also because they can play many instruments.

Except for maybe the Indian classical music tradition playing quarter-tones on there, sitar music theory is universal.

@NeilMeyer - where did sitar get a mention?

In my (rather small) experience, learning musical theory from texts for piano does not pose serious difficulties. It might be however a bit time consuming when doing exercises, as for guitar one has to transpose the melodies and write them in a single clef. I have found a couple of texts (see below) that treat musical theory as applied specifically for guitar — however, I must say that I learned from them little what would be specific for guitar (they don't even contain the basic tricks regarding harmonizing for guitar that one quickly learns by trial-and-error — like using mostly close voicing, switching to tonalities that allow using open bass strings, etc.)

Fred Harz, Harmonielehre für Gitarre — originally in German, but probably exists also in translation. A fairy classical tonal harmonic approach, including introduction to the necessary terminology (although assuming that one already knows to read guitar score.)
Lance Bosman, Harmony for Guitar — a very interesting and enlightening book, with lots of examples from compositions for guitar. However, a bit too esoteric in terms of do-it-yourself stuff — without previous background in harmony it would not be sufficient.

What I wrote above mostly applies to classical finger-style guitar. For less theoretically inclined one can find many books (and online tutorials!), such as Music Theory for Guitar by Wolfsohn or Fretboard harmony by Bishop — (both are excellent books, but a bit light to my taste — e.g., Bishop has no staffs, only tablature, whereas Wolfsohn speaks about simple chord progressions, but nothing about voice leading.)


I'm wondering if it's advisable to apply each new subject I learn to both piano and guitar, and if this will help to deepen my understanding.

Absolutely without a doubt, yes. Especially if you learn to sing at the same time and spend a few years at it, you’ll grow massively in your musical skills.

Thanks for the ideas. I didn't know that singing can be helpful in this context.

@User It would even more deepen your understanding. But you’ll learn a lot even if you don’t learn singing also.

@User Singing is the simple extension of a natural attitude (speech and vocalization). This means that if you can sing something, it'll probably be easier to play the same on your instrument(s). Many musical learning methods are based on speech and singing exactly for that same reason.

Absolutely, yes. It's just what I did, a long time ago. If I didn't understand something well on one instrument, then the other came out to play and made things much clearer.
Mostly the piano helped, as it's set out perfectly graphically - go right, pitch goes up, go left, you know. And all the notes were only in one place, ever. Unlike guitar. where one note may be played in several different places.
Harmonics only made sense on guitar. Bass clef only made sense on piano!
Other aspect of music theory worked well, but in different ways, on both - they sort of complemented each other.
So, yes, don't hesitate. It'll also be another string to your bow, so to speak...

Yes, apply the theory concepts to both instruments! Each instrument has its own physical norms and idioms, but music theory is meant to form foundations across any instruments and expanding your knowledge of those foundations applies to guitar and piano both. You'll be forming new mental connections as you work to connect the intellectual concepts to the physical playing skills on each instrument. Music theory is not specific per instrument; it's a set of communication skills.
